# How to add a custom column on particular store in sales order grid in M2

Tags: magento2

I have added a custom column (PO Number) in sales_order_grid.

Now I have to show that column in particular store when we filter that store that column should appear. Any suggestions on how should I do that.

[image]

Comment: hi @amritsingh please check with my answer & let me know u r thoughts

Answer (score 0):

Here I have used attribute **export_status**.

> app/code/Magently/Ajax/view/adminhtml/ui_component/sales_order_grid.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <columns name="sales_order_columns">
        <column name="export_status" class="Magently\Ajax\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Status">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">XML Exported</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

> app/code/Magently/Ajax/Ui/Component/Listing/Column/Status.php

```
<?php
namespace Magently\Ajax\Ui\Component\Listing\Column;

use \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface;
use \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface;
use \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory;
use \Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column;
use \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder;

class Status extends Column
{
    protected $_orderRepository;
    protected $_searchCriteria;

    public function __construct(ContextInterface $context, UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory, OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository, SearchCriteriaBuilder $criteria, array $components = [], array $data = [])
    {
        $this->_orderRepository = $orderRepository;
        $this->_searchCriteria  = $criteria;
        parent::__construct($context, $uiComponentFactory, $components, $data);
    }

    public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
    {
        if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
            foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as & $item) {

                $order  = $this->_orderRepository->get($item["entity_id"]);
                $status = $order->getData("export_status");             

                // $this->getData('name') returns the name of the column so in this case it would return export_status
                $item[$this->getData('name')] = $status;
            }
        }

        return $dataSource;
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually, I have two stores one for England and second for Ireland. I have to show PO Number only in England store.

Comment: @AmritPalSingh supre question yar now i understood  let me try and getback to u